# Restrict non compiled java file(a file having compilation errors) from checkin using tortoise svn/eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN and eclipse SVN plugin. 
I want to show a error message when user is going to check-in not compiled java file(a file having compilation errors).

Is it possible by some way.

Please let me know as i want to implement it as check-in policies in my project.

Thanks,
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with a hook script.  Specifically a `pre-commit` hook scripts.  The [Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) section of the SVN Book documents how.

I'd probably do it by using the [validate-files.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/validate-files.py) script that's included in the Subversion source since 1.8.0 under [tools/hook-scripts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/).  There is an example configuration named [validate-files.conf.example].[4](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/validate-files.conf.example)

The basic setup is validate-files.py goes into the hooks directory of your repo named `pre-commit` and your customed conf file goes in the conf directory named `validate-files.conf`.

The general idea behind validate-files.py is you can set it up to run commands when specific patterns are matched against the files in the commit and then if the command exits with a non-zero exit code an error is returned to the user.

In your specific case I think this may be somewhat hard no matter how you go about it because in order to compile and check a Java file it needs access to other classes.  So in the end you may need to run your build system.  Which makes it pretty much impossible for me to provide you this piece.

You may be better served by simply having a build system that runs builds and then generates messages to the developers when this happens.  The added benefit there is that these builds can be saved and used as definitive builds for a given project at a given revision.  There are quite a few such systems out there.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I agree that we can do it using pre-commit hooks. But when i use eclipse it compiles the code automatically and i want to take the advantage of it. is there any svn plug-in made for eclipse which provides this facility.